# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scanpy' (python)

Tags: python, bioinformatics, scanpy

I've installed scanpy, and when I check with `pip show` it's there:

```
C:\Users\plain>pip show scanpy
Name: scanpy
Version: 1.8.2
Summary: Single-Cell Analysis in Python.
Home-page: http://github.com/theislab/scanpy
Author: Alex Wolf, Philipp Angerer, Fidel Ramirez, Isaac Virshup, Sergei Rybakov, Gokcen Eraslan, Tom White, Malte Luecken, Davide Cittaro, Tobias Callies, Marius Lange, Andrés R. Muñoz-Rojas
Author-email: f.alex.wolf@gmx.de, philipp.angerer@helmholtz-muenchen.de
License:
Location: c:\users\plain\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
Requires: anndata, h5py, joblib, matplotlib, natsort, networkx, numba, numpy, packaging, pandas, patsy, scikit-learn, scipy, seaborn, sinfo, statsmodels, tables, tqdm, umap-learn
Required-by:
```

But when I try to import it into Jupyter Notebook, I get an error message:

```
import scanpy as sc
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-0074c9bc0b31> in <module>
----> 1 import scanpy as sc

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scanpy'
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: When working with Jupyter notebook, the best hack when facing importing problems is just to reset the kernel. In short, when the kernel starts, it uses every library currently in the system with that specific version, and will **not** change whatsoever if you use pip to upgrade it or install new things.

Comment: After reading your comment. I tried resetting the kernel, but I still got ModuleNotFoundError . Then I tried importing it into Spyder, and I still got ModuleNotFoundError. So in this case I'm guessing it's not a Jupyter Notebook specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases I always check that Python "sees" my environment. Easiest way is to print Pythonpath. Run this code in jupyter notebook to ensure that Python is aware about scanpy installation path:

```py
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Your folder `c:\users\plain\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages` should be amongst printed paths

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error just now while importing scanpy library into my googlecolab environment.
I entered '!pip install scanpy' . Following the successful installation of scanpy'. I was able to import the scanpy' library.
I hope this worked for whoever encountered the same problem.

Comment: In the question he says he already pip installed it. Is your answer a solution for "I pip installed it _and_ its still not working", or simply "I forgot to pip install it"?